Next JS cant build due to getServerSideProps not being used and next export interference
I have been building a web app with Next JS and it's so far been great!
I have used CRA in the past to build my web apps and the flow has been similar with a few new things to learn.
I am now facing an issue thats driving me bananas. I cannot build my app because of a dynamic page I have set up that fetches details for different projects.
Everything works gracefully in dev, but when building i get the following error:
The "next export" command has been removed in favor of "output: export" in next.config.js. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

Right, so I re-add output: 'export' in my next config... just to get this error:
Error: Page "/project/[projectId]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config.

I cannot seem to get around this. Why can't it just work like it does in dev? I have been doing research all week and it seem like they want me to create static pages of every single data point, but there will be hundreds!
I want to only fetch this data on request but they really don't make this straight forward.
Here is my dynamic component simplified:
export default function Project({ params }) {
  const isMobile = useMobileState();
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [audioData, setAudioData] = useState([]);
  const [infoData, setInfoData] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);


  const fetchSongs = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const dbRef = ref(db);
    const snapshot = await get(ref(db, `projects/${params.projectId}`));
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      const dataSongs = snapshot.val().songs;
      const dataInfo = snapshot.val().info;

      const dataArray = Object.keys(dataSongs).map(key => ({
        ...dataSongs[key],
        id: key
      }));

      return { songs: dataArray, info: dataInfo };
    } else {
      return { songs: [], info: {} };
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSongs().then(({ songs, info }) => {
      setAudioData(songs);
      setInfoData(info);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);


  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      {/* DISPLAY DATA HERE */}
    </main>
  );
}


generateStaticParams is used in combination with dynamic route segments to statically generate routes at build time instead of on-demand at request time. So what you are experienceing is actually how it is supposed to be.
If  your data updates every now and then you can use revalidate, like this.
export const revalidate = 60; //revalidate this page every 60 seconds
in generateStaticParams you basically want to give instructions on what is supposed to be done with the dynamic route. Fro example in a blog you could fetch the data according to the input slug.
I do not know what exactly your project is about but I hope this could lead you in the right direction
